# how can I do partition on hive external table use exist HDFS files

Tags: hive, hdfs

I want to create an external table use files that already stored in HDFS
hdfs://my/hdfs/location

```
/user/db/testfiles/test1.txt
/user/db/testfiles/test2.txt
/user/db/testfiles/test3.txt
/user/db/testfiles/test4.txt
```

Since I don't want to move those files to hive folder, how can I do partition on current folder use these files?

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_name (  col1 STRING,
col2 STRING,
col3 STRING
)
partitioned by (col4 STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION '/user/db/testfiles'
;
```

Comment: There is no such thing as an "hive folder". What is your motivation here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add partition one by one.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name ADD PARTITION(col4='1') LOCATION '/user/db/testfiles/test1.txt';
ALTER TABLE tbl_name ADD PARTITION(col4='2') LOCATION '/user/db/testfiles/test2.txt';
ALTER TABLE tbl_name ADD PARTITION(col4='3') LOCATION '/user/db/testfiles/test3.txt';
ALTER TABLE tbl_name ADD PARTITION(col4='4') LOCATION '/user/db/testfiles/test4.txt';
```